# DraftJS with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reactjs, babeljs, draftjs

Rendering DraftJS Editor on IE11 gives the following error - 
`Invariant Violation: PluginEditor.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

This same setup works fine in Chrome/FF. We already use babel for transpiling ES6.

- A related Github thread (https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/296) mentioned multiple versions of React (since draft includes version 15+) while my app uses `v0.14...` I tried this, but upgrading isn't feasible right now)
- The documentation mentions using `es6-shim` along with `es5-shim` (https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/advanced-topics-issues-and-pitfalls.html#polyfills). I tried this but it didn't help. I get the same error.

Anything else I might be missing? Looking forward to your inputs.

Comment: I have checked out the site https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/ on IE11 and all is working.

I can only imagine that there is a mistake in the rendering of your component? Are there any other errors in the console?

Comment: @GarryTaylor: `Invariant Violation: PluginEditor.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Comment: They are a pain in the ass to debug. There's something wrong with code that's rendering the JSX. The Render is not returning anything (normally due to a bug in the JS. What is the "PluginEditor" Component? Can you post this code? I am assuming this is a wrapper (HOC) for the Editor, but I need to see the code.

Comment: @GarryTaylor `PluginEditor` is the name of the editor component internally in the `draft-js-plugins-editor` which is then publicly exported as `Editor`. Will try to post more code. Nothing fancy, a very bare-bones editor also fails.